# Make GCC / G++ link using a C preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, c-preprocessor

How can I make `gcc` tell `ld` to link with a library using a preprocessor directive from within the code itself?

I have a very long, undocumented and hard to read cmake file that generates a hard to read makefile that *I have to use* and putting the link command right next to its `#include` would save me weeks of headache with no guaranteed success.

Comment: #pragma (system-specific) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard way as far as I know. There are proprietary implementations, like with MS compilers, but I know of no universal way.